# How to make a Doctrine subquery?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two mysql tables and corresponding entities:

```
Question
--------
id
text
level


Asked
--------
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="QuestionEntity")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question", referencedColumnName="id")
question 
user
```

I want to query for all questions that has a specific level and the question haven't been asked from a given user. How can I do this with an entity manager query builder? 
With MySQL syntax the query would be:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Question
WHERE 
  Question.level = 1
  AND Question.id NOT IN( SELECT Asked.question FROM Asked WHERE Asked.user = 23)
```

I tried multiple things like Tomasz Madeyski commented, but I still got 500 Internal Server Error. This is my code: (I tested the subquery and it was fine when it is stand alone)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $fbUser = $em->getRepository(FbUserEntity::class)->findOneBy(['fbId' => $session->get('fb_user_id')]);

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $qb;

$questions = $qb->select('q')
    ->from('MyBundle:QuestionEntity', 'q')
    ->where('q.level = :level')
    ->setParameter('level', $level)
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notIn(
        'q.id',
        $qb2->select('a.question')
            ->from('LMyBundle:AskedEntity', 'a')
            ->where('a.user = :userid')
            ->setParameter('userid', $fbUser->getId())
            ->getDQL()
    ))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: HTTP 500 error:
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error". The worst is that I don't get any error message so I don't have an idea what's going wrong.

Comment: you should check your logs to know what's actually wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$subQuery = $qb->select('a.question')
    ->from('YourBundle:Asked', 'a')
    ->andWhere('a.user = 23')


$query = $qb->select('q')
    ->from('YourBundle:Question', 'q')
    ->andWhere('q.level = 1')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->notIn('q.id', $subQuery->getDQL())
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```

The key here is `$qb->expr()->notIn()` part

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the logs I figured out that instead of

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $qb;
```

I should create a new queryBuilder for qb2:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
```

But this still gives me an error. After some experimentingI figured out that if the subquery is executed, it gives something like this format:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'question' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'question' => int 2
```

So I run through the subquery result like this:

```
$alreadyAsked = [];
foreach($asked as $q){
    $alreadyAsked[] = $q['question'];
}
```

And pass the $alreadyAsked array to the main query like this, then it works:

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->notIn('q.id', $alreadyAsked))
```